# How to store zend access objects in session in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, zend-framework, google-calendar-api

I am trying to store the Zend calendar library access object namely "service" in codeigniter controller which could be accessed in any function within the controller for future use. I tried to store it in a class variable and accessed it as "$this->service" but the object returned to empty. The next technique was to store the object in session which is also returning an empty variable. The code for the session storage of the object which I have written is as following:

My Controller:

```
class calendar extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();

        $clientPath = APPPATH."libraries";
        $oldPath = set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $clientPath);

        require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';
        Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata');
        Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin');
        Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Calendar');

    }

    public function connect_with_google(){

        // User whose calendars you want to access
        $user = 'email@email.com';
        $pass = 'mypassword';
        $service = Zend_Gdata_Calendar::AUTH_SERVICE_NAME; // predefined service name for calendar
        $client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient($user, $pass, $service);
        $service = new Zend_Gdata_Calendar($client);
        $this->session->set_userdata('service', $service);

    }

    public function ajax_get_calendars()
    {
      var_dump($this->session->userdata('service'));
    }
}

/* End of file welcome.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/welcome.php */
```

Comment: What outputs `var_dump($service);` before `$this->session->set_userdata('service', $service);`?

Comment: $service is basically the object returned by Zeng Google Library which is used to access calendars !

Comment: That is not what I have asked you... I know what that library does.

Comment: Then you want the output ?

Comment: Yes. And also what prints `var_dump($this->session->userdata('service'));`... The error might not be in Codeigniter session class.

Comment: The object is too long wont fit here ?

Comment: And I would also have to remover credentials from the object !!!

Comment: You could post it on [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/) and put the link here

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Yyubp2uW these are respective the outputs

Comment: I worked with `Codeigniter`, `Zend` is not for me. I thought that `$service` variable was the result as a string or array type. Try to `serialize` the `$service` variable before storing into the session and `unserialize` it after getting it back.